# TextInputDialog error

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8

i have a problem with showing my TextInputDialog in JavaFX application. In code:

```
 TextInputDialog tid = new TextInputDialog("Your name");
    tid.setTitle("Table");
    tid.setHeaderText("You have won!");
    tid.setContentText("Enter your name: ");
    tid.showAndWait();
```

And i got an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Timer-2
```

And yes, i use timers, three or four in my application.

GitHub - https://github.com/verygoodat/FlappyBox
/src/Application/GameController/ - function setState(int), switch(2), i should create a message at the and of the game, but i can't.
So, what may cause this problem?

---

This `Platform.runLater(() -> tid.showAndWait())` didn't work

```
case 2://pause
            TextInputDialog tid = new TextInputDialog("Ваше имя");
            tid.setTitle("Таблица рекордов");
            tid.setHeaderText("Вы побили чей-то рекорд!");
            tid.setContentText("Введите ваше имя: ");
            Platform.runLater(() -> tid.showAndWait());
            Timers.stopTimers();
            pr.setFill(Color.rgb(0,0,0,0.5));
            pr.clearRect(0,0,pre.getWidth(), pre.getHeight()-50);
            pr.fillRect(0,0,pre.getWidth(), pre.getHeight());
            pr.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            stat = "КОНЕЦ ИГРЫ!";
            pr.fillText(stat, WIDTH/2-150, HEIGHT/2);
            pr.fillText( "\nPOINTS: "+gamecontroller.score, WIDTH/2-170, HEIGHT/2);
            gameover = true;
            break;
```

---

It works like this:

```
 Platform.runLater(() ->
            {
                TextInputDialog tid = new TextInputDialog();
                tid.setTitle("Таблица рекордов");
                tid.setHeaderText("Вы побили чей-то рекорд!");
                tid.setContentText("Введите ваше имя: ");
                tid.showAndWait();
            });
```

Comment: *"And yes, i use timers, three or four in my application."* Consider swapping to `AnimationTimer`/a `Transition` or `Timeline`, if you're modifying the scene form those timers.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaFX, anything that updates the UI needs to run on the FX application thread. You can do whatever else you want in your own threads, with timers, etc. but you should show the TextInputDialog on the Application thread.

You can do it like this:

```
Platform.runLater(()->tid.showAndWait());
```

Comment: So, i need to specify a thread for my textinputdialog? It doesn't know where it should be?

Comment: How would it 'know where it should be'? It attempts to execute on the thread it's on, in this case 'Timer-2', which isn't allowed to change things on the FX application thread, which is why you have that error.

Comment: And i have another question. In my general class (Application/GameController), i have static implementation of this class, and i have two or three variables, which are modified from another classes (like Game/Player, function Collision, where i change my lifes and score) with this static implementation. But in my GameController class i cant just say System.out.print(score) (for ex), cause it will write  0, even it is not so, but gamecontroller.score will give right value. Whats the problem with that?

Comment: @IlyaFalko That is another question and should be asked as such, comments aren't the place for asking new questions.